# Skaffold with non-blocking program

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Say I want to deploy a pod with skaffold that will *not* contain a continuously running/blocking program. E.g. take the [getting started example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/getting-started) and change `main.go` to:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

If I run `skaffold dev` with the above modified example and just wait without making any changes to the code, the pod will continuously restart, cycling through statuses `Completed` -> `CrashLoopBackOff` -> `Completed`, with each restart running the program in the pod again. How do I get the pod to run the program once while only rerunning/restarting the pod on changes to the code?

This is with skaffold v1.6.0-docs, ubuntu 18, microk8s 1.16/stable, having set `skaffold config set default-repo localhost:32000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would like to emphasize that there is nothing specific to **Skaffold**. It is rather related with the very nature of kubernetes `Pod` which is not meant to run to completion but rather keep running (at least with its default settings).

You can easily verify it by running a `Pod` from [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#pod-templates) example in a few differant variants:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 3600']
```

Try to reduce sleep time to some shorter value and you'll observe that it is also constantly changing between `Completed` and `CrashLoopBackOff` states. It will also happen when you remove the command which keeps the container up and running.

If you run:

```
kubectl get pod myapp-pod -o yaml
```

you may notice that there is `restartPolicy` defined in `Pod` specification and if you don't set it explicitely to a different value, by default it is set to `Always`. Here you have the reason why your `Completed` `Pods` are constantly restarted.

**Setting it to `Never` should give you the result you want to achieve.**:

```
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox
    ...
```

However bear in mind that you typically won't be using bare `Pods` for running your workload in **kubernetes**. You will rather use controllers such as `Deployment` that manage them. As long as `Deployment` is used to ensure that certain set of `Pods` is up and running, **for running something to completion** you have in **kubernetes** another controller, named [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

Comment: Thanks! My actual use case was to use skaffold to deploy a pod running tests. Switching skaffold to deploy a job instead of a pod works for me and the tests will only execute once, as opposed to every time the pod restarted which was my orignal problem. Is there a better/more idiomatic way to deploy a pod running tests?

Comment: It depends on what you are performing those tests against. If these are other `Pods` on the same cluster, I think using `Job` or a simple `Pod` with `restartPolicy` set to `Never` is the appropriate solution. Skaffold pipeline also includes testing stage but it is designed for [container-structure-tests](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test) on built images, so I suppose this is not the kind of test that you need in your use case.